# TFS - checkout in wrong folder, folder deleted -> trouble

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am experiencing trouble with the following:

In VS 2010, I followed these steps:

File -> Source control -> Open from source control

I selected a solution file from a project in TFS, and opened the project (obviously).

Unfortunately I opened the project in an incorrect folder, and I thought "If I delete the folder(s) and reopen the solution from TFS, everything will be fine". My bad!

TFS "reminds" that I checked out the project to this specific location, so now when I want to check it out again, the location box is greyed out.

Anybody got any clue how to fix this???

Thanks in advance!

Nico

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answer Richard! Unfortunately this wasn't exactly what I needed, but I found the solution.

In Source Control Explorer, browse to the mapped source, right click and select "remove mappings".

Here you can edit the mappings to your local sources :)

Check out again and everything is in the right place!

Answer (score 1):

There is a force option with get which will override TFS's knowledge odf the state of the workspace:

- In Team Explorer use Get Specific Version: select latest as the version and tick "Overwrite all files ..."
- With `tf.exe` use `/force`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard! 

Unfortunately this wasn't exactly what I needed, but I found the solution.

In Source Control Explorer, browse to the mapped source, right click and select "remove mappings". Here you can edit the mappings to your local sandbox. :) Check out again and everything is in the right place :)

Comment: You don't always want to overwrite your local work space with the version that is checked in. If you don't have any pending changes than, yes, this is the easiest fix. Which is lame.

Answer (score 1):

open source control. Go to the folder right click and select Add/ Edit Mapping whichever is available. This will prompt to download the new version. Do so and you will be good to go.